# Doctrine - Multiple models referencing same id field in another model

Tags: php, sql, doctrine

I have a Files Model, and Multiple (currently 3) different other Models (Article, Job, Event) that can all have files, that are stored in the Files Model.

The problem is that when i generate the tables via the CLI-Tool (./doctrine build-all-reload), i get this error message:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot 
add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`my_database/articles`, CONSTRAINT `articles_id_files_target_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `files` (`target_id`))
```

File is defined as (No relations are defined in this Model defined):

```
columns:
  id:
    primary: true
    autoincrement: true
    type: integer(4)
  target_id: integer(4)
  filename: string(255)
[...]
```

All 4 Models have this relation-definition:

```
  relations:
    Files:
      type: many
      class: File
      local: id
      foreign: target_id
```

This is the Php-Code that Doctrine generates (BaseFile.php):

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->hasOne('Publication', array(
         'local' => 'target_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));

    $this->hasOne('Event', array(
         'local' => 'target_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));

    $this->hasOne('Article', array(
         'local' => 'target_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));

    $this->hasOne('Job', array(
         'local' => 'target_id',
         'foreign' => 'id'));
}
```

I understand *why* this happens (The Constraints can not be setup for multiple tables), but have no idea how i could solve this problem without mutltiple file tables or an association table.

Is there a way to tell Doctrine that it should not create the relations in the File model?

Any good ideas?

Comment: Might I ask why you don't solve it using an association table? It's a very flexible and efficient solution since it will allow you to link the same file to different content types without uploading it multiple times. With your current model this is impossible...

Comment: Could i really solve this with one association table? how would i let doctrine know about the "type" field?

Comment: I don't know how to make this happen with doctrine, but the problem probably lies with doctrine adding a table that is dependent on another table **before** that other table has been created.

Comment: Doctrine needs to create relations in both the Files and other models so it knows the relationship between the tables. Try defining the relations in the Files model and use the `owningSide: true` directive. http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/defining-models#relationships

Comment: I get confused as to what you're trying to do here. Do all other models have one/many related files or what?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same integer(4) type everywhere? You would get the same error if you get the types wrong. Besides this being a funky data model, I think it should work? Could you post the full relevant parts of you datamodel?

Answer (score 0):

try if you need,
relations:

```
Files:
  type: many
  class: File
  local: target_id
  foreign: id
Files2:
  type: many
  class: File
  local: id
  foreign: id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
columns:
    id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true, primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    target_id:  { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    model:       { type: string, notnull: true }
```

Files model needs to know the id and the model of linked entry. So, in Files.class.php you can also specify:

```
public function getArticles() {
    if (strcmp($this->getModel(), 'Articles')) {
        return Doctrine::getTable('Articles')->findOneById($this->getTargetId());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Probably there's a better way, but in this case you have 1 table, you don't need any more relations, but you have to specify getters/setters by yourself. So it depends on your goals whether this will fir or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Doctrine Inheritance Mapping. Basically you need to create abstract file entity (model) and the concrete file entities (extended from abstract file entity) for each of article, job and event. Then each of Article, Job and Event should have one to many connection to ArticleFile, JobFile and EventFile respectively. Check code samples below:

```php
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "article" = "ArticleFileEntity",
 *     "job" = "JobFileEntity",
 *     "event" = "EventFileEntity"
 * })
 * @ORM\Table(name="file")
 */
abstract class AbstractFile 
{
 private int $id;
}
```

```php
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ArticleFileEntity extends AbstractFileEntity 
{
}
```

```php
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer")
 * @package Modules\Customer\Domain\Entities
 */
class ArticleEntity 
{
     /**
     * Article file collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ArticleFileEntity", cascade={"persist","remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected Collection $files;
}
```

REF: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/inheritance-mapping.html